# Reference counting while adding element to list

Tags: python, list, reference

From [listobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Include/listobject.h)

I read this line:

"PyList_SetItem does not increment the new item's reference
count, but does decrement the reference count of the item it replaces,
if not nil.  It does *decrement* the reference count if it is *not*
inserted in the list.  Similarly, PyList_GetItem does not increment the
returned item's reference count."

But when i tested reference count of the element got increased.

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
3
>>> ls = [1,2]
>>> ls.append(a)
>>> ls
[1, 2, 'abc']
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
4
>>> ls.insert(1,a)
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
5
>>>
```

Please correct me if i wrong or explain me how it is ?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `append` knows about this quirk of `PyList_SetItem` and deals with the reference count increment.

This is really the only way it could work.  Reference counting is really a facet of the implementation, and -- `getrefcount` notwithstanding -- not something Python programmers have to deal with.

To put it another way, you only need to worry about whether an API steals a reference or makes a new reference if you are writing an extension in C.  If you stick to Python, you are safe.

Answer (score 1):

That basically means that the *caller* to `PyList_SetItem` must take care of reference counting;

In the case of `append`, it is implemented in [`PyList_Append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L303y) which is a simple wrapper arround [`app1(PyListObject *, PyObject *)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L283y) and there [it is in fact increasing the refrence count.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L297y)

[`PyList_Insert`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L273y) also calls into [`ins1(PyListObject *, Py_ssize_t, PyObject *)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L240y), which also [increases the referene count](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/218fc7bebc369150163058b0763919e12f0bc102/Objects/listobject.c#L267y).

Comment: so how to invoke PyList_SetItem?  ls = list(a)