# Deleting Python object reference (reference counting)

Tags: python, reference

I know when Python handles object, it uses 'reference' to the object, not the real value itself.

But behavior of below code seems very odd to me.
5 dummy object references were copied from `prev` to `now` list, then `prev` was cleared.

Then, shouldn't references stored in `now` be invalidated too?

```
class dummy:
    pass

prev = [dummy() for _ in range(5)] 

now = []
for d in prev:
    now.append(d)

for idx in range(5):
    print(prev[idx] is now[idx]) # all True - so, same reference copied

prev.clear()
print(prev) # empty
print(now) # 5 'dummy' objects survived - How??
```

I found possible duplicate to this question, and would like to ask if this is the reason why references in `now` isn't invalidated after `prev.clear()`
[Python: Delete object referenced from tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217878/python-delete-object-referenced-from-tuple)

Maybe I'm too used to reference concept in C++ and Python is different.

Comment: Could this be of any assistance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700215/reference-counting-while-adding-element-to-list

Comment: The short answer is now.  There was one reference to each of the Dummy() objects.  Then you made 'now` be a list of all your Dummy objects, so each Dummy object is pointed to twice.  Then you removed one of your pointers, and each Dummy() object still has one pointer left.  The object doesn't go away until there is no way left for you to access it, (except through special hooks).

Comment: I see. So it is related to reference counting. I think I got this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding each object in `prev` to `now`, you increment their reference counts by 1, so they become 2.

When you delete the objects in `prev`, reference count of each object is decremented by 1, and they become 1.

Since reference counts of the objects did not reach 0, they do not go away.